# Report or Query to show all Approval Processes and their Criteria

Tags: approval-process, standard-objects, process

Is it possible to run a report on approval processes and display their entry criteria?
What is the name of the object/field where Entry Criteria are stored?
No fields on the ProcessDefinition object have helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Salesforce support and Developer board, this is sadly not possible:

> You can't query the 'metadata' information (like Entry Criteria)
>   regarding an Approval/Workflow Process with Apex. You could try the
>   metadata API to query some amount of metadata regarding Workflow
>   Rules, but even the Metadata API does not support Approval Processes.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008yNYIAY